# Не отображается график matplotlib в окне tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, numpy

Пустой экран при вводе данных в программу. Пока не добавил окно matplotlib в tkinter все работало. Может это из-за графика зависит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry ('900x900+600+300')

def draw_graph():
    x, y, z, X, Y, mask = makeData()
    global canvas1
    if canvas1:
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()
    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=100)
    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = win)
    canvas1.draw()
    axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_blue', ['b', 'g', 'y', 'r'], 256)
    axes.scatter(x, y, z *(1 + mask * 0.75), c=z *(1 + mask * 0.75), cmap=cmap)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1, win)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.NONE, expand=0)
    win.after(200, None)

def makeData():
    a=int(q.get()) #19
    b=float(w.get()) #20
    c=int(e.get()) #200
    x0=float(t.get()) #19.3
    y0=float(u.get()) #19.6
    r=float(i.get()) #.1
    x = np.linspace(a, b, c)  # создаем массив из 100 чисел float от 19 до 20 с равномернов шагом
    y = np.linspace(a, b, c)
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    z = np.random.normal(xgrid, ygrid)
    r = .1  # радиус маски
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    mask = (X - x0) ** 2 + (Y - y0) ** 2 < r ** 2
    return xgrid, ygrid, z, X, Y, mask

canvas1 = None
tk.Label(win, text='Введите начало массива a = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите конец массива b = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите количество точек массива:  ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по x от a = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по y до b = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Радиус маски r = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

q = tk.Entry()
w = tk.Entry()
e = tk.Entry()
t = tk.Entry()
u = tk.Entry()
i = tk.Entry()

q.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
w.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
e.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
t.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
u.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
i.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

tk.Button(win, text='Ввести точки', command=draw_graph).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитал по поводу создания различных графиков в Matplotlib тут: https://devpractice.ru/matplotlib-lesson-5-1-mplot3d-toolkit/#p4

В соответствие с информацией о построение графиков "Поверхность" изменил отрисовку осей:

```
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_blue', ['b', 'g', 'y', 'r'], 256)
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z *(1 + mask * 0.75), cmap=cmap)
```

В общем виде код выглядит так:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry ('900x900+600+300')

def draw_graph():
    x, y, z, X, Y, mask = makeData()
    global canvas1
    if canvas1:
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()
    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=100)
    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = win)
    canvas1.draw()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('red_blue', ['b', 'g', 'y', 'r'], 256)
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z *(1 + mask * 0.75), cmap=cmap)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1, win)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.NONE, expand=0)
    win.after(200, None)


def makeData():
    a=int(q.get()) #19
    b=float(w.get()) #20
    c=int(e.get()) #200
    x0=float(t.get()) #19.3
    y0=float(u.get()) #19.6
    r=float(i.get()) #.1
    x = np.linspace(a, b, c)  # создаем массив из 100 чисел float от 19 до 20 с равномернов шагом
    y = np.linspace(a, b, c)
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    z = np.random.normal(xgrid, ygrid)
    r = .1  # радиус маски
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    mask = (X - x0) ** 2 + (Y - y0) ** 2 < r ** 2
    return xgrid, ygrid, z, X, Y, mask

canvas1 = None
tk.Label(win, text='Введите начало массива a = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите конец массива b = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите количество точек массива:  ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по x от a = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по y до b = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
tk.Label(win, text='Радиус маски r = ').pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

q = tk.Entry()
w = tk.Entry()
e = tk.Entry()
t = tk.Entry()
u = tk.Entry()
i = tk.Entry()

q.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
w.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
e.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
t.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
u.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
i.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

tk.Button(win, text='Ввести точки', command=draw_graph).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
win.mainloop()
```

[image: График выводит в таком виде]

Answer (score 0):

Для более удобного вида программы лучше применить позиционирование .grid(column,row)

```
tk.Label(win, text='Введите начало массива a = ').grid(column=1,row=1)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите конец массива b = ').grid(column=1,row=2)
tk.Label(win, text='Введите количество точек массива:  ').grid(column=1,row=3)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по x от a = ').grid(column=1,row=4)
tk.Label(win, text='Центр маски по y до b = ').grid(column=1,row=5)
tk.Label(win, text='Радиус маски r = ').grid(column=1,row=6)

q.grid(column=2,row=1)
w.grid(column=2,row=2)
e.grid(column=2,row=3)
t.grid(column=2,row=4)
u.grid(column=2,row=5)
i.grid(column=2,row=6)

tk.Button(win, text='Ввести точки', command=draw_graph).grid(column=2,row=7)
```

Почитайте побольше о размещении виджетов в tkinter

А какой график при этих введенных данных должен получиться?

Comment: Добавил картинку которую хочу получить. Да с grid тоже пробовал, но тоже самое, поэтому грешу на изображение 3д.